# Unable to break the JSON file into two using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to break this JSON file into two parts

1st Part: The Header Part which contains all the information present before "line:10" or "in_network" Key

2nd Part: The detail Part which contains all the information present inside the key "in_network"

Here is what JSON file looks like

```
{
  "reporting_entity_name": "launcher",
  "reporting_entity_type": "launcher",
  "plan_name": "launched",
  "plan_id_type": "hios",
  "plan_id": "1111111111",
  "plan_market_type": "individual",
  "last_updated_on": "2020-08-27",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "in_network": [
    {
      "negotiation_arrangement": "ffs",
      "name": "Boosters",
      "billing_code_type": "CPT",
      "billing_code_type_version": "2020",
      "billing_code": "27447",
      "description": "Boosters On Demand",
      "negotiated_rates": [
        {
          "provider_groups": [
            {
              "npi": [
                0
              ],
              "tin": {
                "type": "ein",
                "value": "11-1111111"
              }
            }
          ],
          "negotiated_prices": [
            {
              "negotiated_type": "negotiated",
              "negotiated_rate": 123.45,
              "expiration_date": "2022-01-01",
              "billing_class": "organizational"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my python code which i am trying to use to this operation:

```
flag = 0
file = open('new_test.JSON', 'r')
detail_file_1 = open('new_test_detail.json', 'a')
detail_file_1.write('{')
detail_file_1.close()
for line in file:
    if flag == 0:
        if line != '  "in_network": [':
            header_file = open('new_test_header.json', 'a')
            header_file.write(line)
            header_file.close()
        else:
            flag = 1
    else:
        detail_file = open('new_test_detail.json', 'a')
        detail_file.write(line)
        detail_file.close()
header_file_1 = open('new_test_header.json', 'a')
header_file_1.write('}')
header_file_1.close()
```

Here is what i expected 1st part file should look like:

```
{
  "reporting_entity_name": "launcher",
  "reporting_entity_type": "launcher",
  "plan_name": "launched",
  "plan_id_type": "hios",
  "plan_id": "1111111111",
  "plan_market_type": "individual",
  "last_updated_on": "2020-08-27",
  "version": "1.0.0",
}
```

Here is what i expected 2nd part file should look like:

```
"in_network": [
    {
      "negotiation_arrangement": "ffs",
      "name": "Boosters",
      "billing_code_type": "CPT",
      "billing_code_type_version": "2020",
      "billing_code": "27447",
      "description": "Boosters On Demand",
      "negotiated_rates": [
        {
          "provider_groups": [
            {
              "npi": [
                0
              ],
              "tin": {
                "type": "ein",
                "value": "11-1111111"
              }
            }
          ],
          "negotiated_prices": [
            {
              "negotiated_type": "negotiated",
              "negotiated_rate": 123.45,
              "expiration_date": "2022-01-01",
              "billing_class": "organizational"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But Unfortunately my code fails to do so. Can some help me with this.

What python code changes is needed to do so.

Comment: "But Unfortunately my code fails to do so." What happens when you try your code? How is that different from the expected result? Also: [did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to look for existing ways to solve the problem, for example by [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=work+with+json+data+in+python)?

Comment: easier way would be to: Read the json into a dict, make copies of the dict, remove the keys that you dont want in those dicts, and write those dicts to a separate files

Comment: that's not a correct way of diving a json file: you need to access the needed keys and put the part somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to divide this JSON into two smaller JSONs I would do the following:

- Read the JSON as a Python dictionary
- Slice the dictionary to two smaller ones using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)
- dump the JSONs into two different `.json` files.

As such:

```py
import json
import itertools


with open('test.json', 'r') as fp:
    data = json.loads(fp.read())


d1 = dict(itertools.islice(data.items(), 8))
d2 = dict(itertools.islice(data.items(), 8, len(data.items())))

# dump these python dictionaries to .json files here
```

#### Output:

**First part:**

```json
{
  "reporting_entity_name": "launcher",
  "reporting_entity_type": "launcher",
  "plan_name": "launched",
  "plan_id_type": "hios",
  "plan_id": "1111111111",
  "plan_market_type": "individual",
  "last_updated_on": "2020-08-27",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

**Second part:**

```json
{
  "in_network": [
    {
      "negotiation_arrangement": "ffs",
      "name": "Boosters",
      "billing_code_type": "CPT",
      "billing_code_type_version": "2020",
      "billing_code": "27447",
      "description": "Boosters On Demand",
      "negotiated_rates": [
        {
          "provider_groups": [
            {
              "npi": [
                0
              ],
              "tin": {
                "type": "ein",
                "value": "11-1111111"
              }
            }
          ],
          "negotiated_prices": [
            {
              "negotiated_type": "negotiated",
              "negotiated_rate": 123.45,
              "expiration_date": "2022-01-01", "billing_class": "organizational"
      }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Now, if it is dynamic and you don't know whether it is at index 8 or not - you can get it using `list(dict.keys()).index`:

```py
print(list(data.keys()).index('version'))
```

I've added one to the `stop` parameter of `islice`, because python always goes from `0` to `stop-1`.